# c# - MySQL if entry is not the same, update with old entry+new entry

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm relatively new to C# and MySQL. My task is to get records and update an database table entry with the responding ID something similar like this **old Database Entry&;new Value**, Because I need to keep the old values for future references. I have a database table with 10 fields and instead of coding a big if-cluster I wanted to ask if there is a neat solution with MySQL Commands or in C# itself. (I already know about **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, But I need to update ONLY if it is NOT a duplication) Thank you in advance.

Edit: Okay I've found a working solution, although I'm sure it's not really pretty. After everything i ignore insert into the databse.

```
using (MySqlCommand getData = new MySqlCommand("SELECT concat(Caller, 'µ', 
Email, 'µ', Category, 'µ', Subcategory, 'µ', INC_Type, 'µ', State, 'µ', 
Priority, 'µ', Description) FROM sn_incidents WHERE Number = '" + 
data.result[i].number + "'", connection))
{
    var getDataResult = ((String)getData.ExecuteScalar()).Split('µ');
    for (int j = 0; j < getDataResult.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (String.Equals(result_Array[j], getDataResult[j])) {
            Console.WriteLine("[Logger] String is Equal.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Logger] No duplication found for field " + 
result_ArrayType[j] + ": " + result_Array[j] + "=/=" + getDataResult[j]);
            result_Array[j] = result_Array[j] + " µ " + getDataResult[j];
            Console.WriteLine("[Logger] New String of " + result_ArrayType[j] 
+ " is now " + result_Array[j]);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldnt your table consist of a composite key rather than an ID column then?

Comment: you're not using an ORM, right? - you use `SqlConnection` directly?

Comment: I guess I wasn't completely clear, sorry. ID is my Primary Key, and I have 9 String Fields which contain various user informations and I only need to update those string fields if they are not the same, keeping the old values too. I use MySqlConnection.

Comment: I'm just wondering, have you looked into Entity framework with MySQL if not i'd strongly suggest you'd do. Made my life a hell of a lot easier. Would also make your code a lot shorter (especialy with linq) and more readable

Comment: No, currently I'm basically just scratching things together. Thank you for the information, will look into it.